# Object/Edit mode AND X-ray switch

Tags: shortcut

I'm writing this thread to talk about the "show whole scene transparent" (x-ray) option: I bet we all agree on the fact that it's fairly similar to the "limit selection to visible" that we had in 2.79's Edit mode (with a big upgrade of course).

The thing is that I only use that when I'm in Edit mode and I prefer having it turned off when I'm in object mode. Yet, the way it works now is that toggling Edit/Object mode does not change the state of the "x-ray" and vice versa.

I would like to know how I could bind the toggle of that visibility option to "tab".

Explanation --> I don't like that I have to do "Alt"+"Z" in addition to "tab" each time I switch between Edit & Object modes. I would like to be able to do both just by tapping "tab".

Is it possible to keep the action that "tab" does (toggle Edit/Object)... And add to that the toggle of the "limit selection to visible"?

I am totally aware that this might only be convenient for me. I'm not asking for it to be implemented by default or so. I just want to know how I can do it locally (maybe some Python lines could help?).

Thanks for reading,

Comment: I agree! I'm also used to having the x-ray in Edit mode only. Switching to Object mode was a fast way to check the changes. Although I like the possibility to have x-ray in object mode as well, I would like to see them separated in some way. The key strokes "Alt"+"Z" is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably relevant: https://cgcookie.com/community/8948-how-do-i-add-the-x-ray-toggle-to-my-z-key-menu#answer-33461

Going to: `Edit - Preferences - Keymap - 3D View - Check Extra Shading Pie Menu items`.

Will produce this kind of result (added `Toggle Overlays` and `Toggle X-Ray`).

[image]

---

PS: this answer is necro but I always struggle with that one and I finally found some keywords leading me there. Looking at the views, it may be useful to other people too.